# access post variables after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my app, I have an AJAX call that POSTs the user's timezone (to the same page) right before a user reloads the page (to see if they switched timezones). Unfortunately, I cannot access that post variable.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ToDoApp.php",
        data: {
            timezone: userTimeZone
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
});
```

I am pretty sure it's because I'm reloading once during the AJAX call and secondly when the page actually reloads. However, I have been going in circles for an hour and can't seem to solve my issue.

**How can I get the timezone variable once the page reloads?**

If there's a better way to solve the problem altogether I'm open to suggestions.

---

More info:

I need the timezone variable on Server-Side to perform timezone conversions, hence my AJAX call. From my comment below:

> So here's the dilemma: I realize timezone are better calculated client
>   side which I am doing with Moment.JS, but I need the timezone variable
>   to do server -side timezone conversions to display dates correctly to
>   the user. That's why I [think I] need an AJAX call, because without it
>   once the page reloads my timezone will be only be available on Client
>   Side and I wont be able to perform my calculations.

Comment: You can't reliably make an ajax request when the user leaves, as there is no guarantee that the request will be done before the browser closes.

Comment: Massive X/Y problem here I suspect. If you're about to reload the page, why do you need an ajax call first? (Which probably won't work, see adeneo's comment.) If you need this information client-side, store it client-side (for instance, `sessionStorage`), but it seems like if we had a better understanding of what you're really trying to accomplish, we could point you in a better direction.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There ***are*** probably massive problems :D So here's the dilemma: I realize timezone are better calculated client side which I am doing with Moment.JS, but I need the timezone variable to do server -side timezone conversions to display dates correctly to the user. That's why I [think I] need an AJAX call, because without it once the page reloads my timezone will be only be available on Client Side and I wont be able to perform my calculations. Did I just go in a circle here...

Comment: @adeneo I never thought of that. very good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's sessionStorage... do the following..

```
//set this anywhere you want in your .js script;
sessionStorage.setItem('TheTimeZone',userTimeZone);

//get the timezone using sessionStorage
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ToDoApp.php",
        data: {
            timezone: sessionStorage.getItem('TheTimeZone')
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
});
```

That should work.

Comment: @ Govind: The key here is that getting it elsewhere (e.g., not in the `beforeunload`) is *also* possible via `sessionStorage.getItem`, even after the page reload.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You have to write app to be able access userTimeZone value in callback. Maybe just return request variables at request results? In that way I suggest to use JSON in place of text format. You can return from script 
ToDoApp.php

```
echo json_encode(array('post'=>$_POST, result=>$result));
```

and access them in callback like: data.post, data.result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      localStorage.setItem("timeZone",new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
    } else {
      // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ToDoApp.php",
        data: {
            // new Date().getTimezoneOffset() gives clients timezone
            timezone: localStorage.getItem("timeZone")
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
});
```

for more :[w3school on timezone](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp)

Comment: please let me know whether it works for you or not.. if worked please upvote and accept as an answer thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your answer veshraj. The issue with this answer is that the variable is not available once the page finishes reloading. This is pretty much what I already have have this and the data is available when the Ajax posts but after reload it's gone.

Comment: i just change my answer you can test over it